# payment method "Check" -> paid?

Tags: expresso-store

I have downloaded de payment method "Check" for Expresso-store. If I make a payment with this payment, the order will be placed on paid. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the 'Paid' order status set as the default? Give a check to your order statuses in Store > Settings > Order Statuses.

Comment: Hello, 

The order status is not default on "Paid". 

Bert

Comment: Currently the Check extension does mark orders as paid (unlike the "Manual" gateway). This may change in future versions of Store but for now is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, 
Hopefully there is a new version soon so that this problem is resolved.